# Selenium webdriver: clicking not working for xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get the webdriver to click on the text "Breaking Things" through `xpath/css` selectors to no avail.  Here is the HTML

```
<div class="org-option" ng-repeat="Org in Organizations" aria-label="Select Breaking Things Organization" ng-click="Org.SelectOrg()" role="button" tabindex="0">
  <div class="data">
    <div class="data-relative">
      <!---->
      <div class="image-wrapper" ng-show="Org.HasImage" ng-if="Org.HasImage" aria-hidden="false">
        <img class="onboard-logo" ng-src="/apiimage/organizations/f1544944fac34442998a05890c400338-0" src="/apiimage/organizations/f1544944fac34442998a05890c400338-0">
      </div>
      <!---->
      <div class="image-wrapper ng-hide" ng-show="!Org.HasImage" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="image-placeholder">
          <div class="center-icon gicon-panorama"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="name-wrapper">
        <div>Breaking Things</div>
```

Here is what I'm doing with the driver:

```
chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='name wrapper']//[text()='Breaking Things']")).click();
```

However it never clicks, what am I missing?  I've also tried implicit waits etc with no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify exact node name `div` or wild-card for "any node" - `*` in this part

```
//[text()='Breaking Things']
```

like below:

```
"//div[@class='name-wrapper']//div[text()='Breaking Things']"
```

or

```
"//div[@class='name-wrapper']//*[text()='Breaking Things']"
```

Answer (score 0):

The class name is `name-wrapper`. The `-` is important

```
chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='name-wrapper']//[text()='Breaking Things']")).click();
```

In `@class='name wrapper'` you are actually telling the `driver` to look for an `WebElement` with **two** classes, `name` and `wrapper`.

Comment: Ooo, yeah you're right on that one - that's what I get for typing it in manually.  Is the syntax correct though?  I've tried it in several different types with it throwing an invalid expression error: